# the button is inactive after successfully moving the page and when returning to the page where the button is still inactive

Tags: javascript, html

how to make the button is inactive after successfully moving the page coba.php and when returning to the page test.php button remains inactive

test.php

```
`<button type="button" id="Btn" onclick="myFunction()">Klik</button>
<script>
 function myFunction() 
   {var x = document.getElementById("Btn");location.href =   
            "coba.php";x.disabled = true;}
</script>`
```

this file
coba.php

`<?php echo "Hallo!" ?>`

Thank you in advance ^_^

Comment: you can refresh the page to reset the button.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want that after the file has been moved successfully you want the button to be disabled

if this is the case, one possible way is to use a variable of type sesssion and check if the page has already been visited as in this example:

test.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<html>
 <body>
   <button onClick="myfunction()" 
   <?php if(isset(session['load'])){echo("disabled");}?>
   >Klik</button>
   <script>
     function myfunction(){
        location.href = "coba.php";}
   </script>
 <body>
<html>
```

the coba.php look like this:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['load'] = "true";
?>
<html>
 <body>
   <?php echo("Hallo!") ?>
   <a href="./index.php"><button>Back</button></a>
 <body>
<html>
```